# VB6 CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession") not able to close session

Tags: oracle, session, vb6, createobject

I have a VB6 application in which I fetch some data from the database.
I am having a problem while closing the created session.

Looks like the session is being retained even after I set the session object to `Nothing`. Seems like it gets closed only when I close the application.

I am using the following query to check the session in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM v$session where terminal='VirtualMachineName';
```

Below is the code,

```vb
Dim pCounter As Long, strLoadSQL As String
Dim objCursor As OraDynaset
Dim tmpDBSessobj As OracleInProcServer.OraSession
Dim tmpDBClientobj As OracleInProcServer.OraDatabase
Dim objresetGI As GameInfo

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set tmpDBSessobj = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
Set tmpDBClientobj = tmpDBSessobj.OpenDatabase(strDBServiceName, strDBUsernamePassword, ORADB_ORAMODE)

'set autocommit false ---
tmpDBClientobj.AutoCommit = False

'set params
Do Until tmpDBClientobj.Parameters.Count = 0
    For pCounter = 0 To tmpDBClientobj.Parameters.Count - 1
        tmpDBClientobj.Parameters.Remove pCounter
    Next
Loop
'bind
tmpDBClientobj.Parameters.Add "ocursor", Nothing, ORAPARM_OUTPUT
tmpDBClientobj.Parameters(0).serverType = ORATYPE_CURSOR

'declare proc signature
strLoadSQL = "begin resetpackage.getresetID(:ocursor); end;"

'reset this game
tmpDBClientobj.ExecuteSQL (strLoadSQL)
Set objCursor = tmpDBClientobj.Parameters(0).Value

'load the list box
If objCursor.RecordCount > 0 Then
    argscollection.Clear
    objCursor.MoveFirst
    Do Until objCursor.EOF
        objresetGI.strGameNo = objCursor.fields(0).Value
        objresetGI.strAction = objCursor.fields(1).Value
        objresetGI.strProcessInd = objCursor.fields(2).Value
        argscollection.Add objresetGI, objCursor.fields(0).Value
    objCursor.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

Set objCursor = Nothing
tmpDBClientobj.Close
Set tmpDBClientobj = Nothing
Set tmpDBSessobj = Nothing
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

objCursor should give you the option to use close and not nothing - `objCursor.Close`